# Composer package structure: development tools placement

Tags: composer-php, project-structure

I'm working on a new composer package. I want to create some classes which override the normal behavior, to aid in development.
I don't really know where to put those classes. Currently my structure is just simply:

```
.
├─ src/
├─ tests/
└─ composer.json
```

I was thinking about putting the mock classes next to the classes they mock in `src/`, but i don't want to "contaminate" the `src/` folder.
I was thinking about extending the structure like this:

```
.
├─ src/
├─ tests/
├─ development/
└─ composer.json
```

I can't really seem to find anything online considering the standard way of doing this, so I don't know if what I'm doing is some sort of big mistake, or if there isn't really any standard for creating such development related classes.

TL;DR: Where to put classes used for development?